# How to switch iframes InternJS

Tags: javascript, selenium, iframe, intern, leadfoot

I need to switch to an iframe that has a dynamic name and id.

```
<iframe name="easyXDM_1435765828615" id="easyXDM_1435765828615">...</iframe>
```

I noticed LeadFoot has a [switchToFrame()](https://theintern.github.io/leadfoot/Session.html#switchToFrame) function, but when I pass it an element that was returned from [find()](https://theintern.github.io/leadfoot/Session.html#find) I get the error "MoveTargetOutOfBounds: POST http.../moveto / {"element":"16"} Offset within element cannot be scrolled into view".

Is there a better way to do this using execute() and some javascript, or how can I make switchToFrame() work?

Comment: What if you pass `easyXDM_1435765828615` string into `switchToFrame()`? Or, is the id dynamically generated?

Comment: It is dynamic.  Currently I am using an xpath //*[contains(@id,"easyXDM_")] to find the iframe.

Comment: Okay, another option: specify the index of the form - e.g. `switchToFrame(1)`.

Comment: It just times out when I pass element.elementId or 1.  Side note element.elementId = 15, but my original code errors with element: 16??

Answer (score 0):

Depending on how your iframes are setup on the page you could try something like this:

```
    .switchToFrame(null)
    .findAllByClassName('iframe')
    .then(
      function(iframes) {
         new remote.constructor(remote.session)
        .switchToFrame(iframes[iframes.length-1])
      }
    )
```

This assumes that the iframe you want to switch to is last to be found, which is obviously a big assumption. You might be able to tweak this though, if the dynamically created iframes appear in the same order every time.